# The puppeteer docker image I built is too large

Tags: javascript, node.js, dockerfile, puppeteer, render

I followed steps I saw online to build a puppeteer docker image for the application that I am working on. The sole purpose of the puppeteer is to create pdf for the application. I decided to create separate api for this.
I deployed it on Render, it fails without showing me any error.
I ran same deocker build locally, it built and started successfully. I noticed that the image was very large. It is 2gig image size.
I felt the docker failed in Render host due to the image size because I am using free account for the testing phase of the app.

Here is my docker file:

```
FROM node:18

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install gnupg wget -y && \
wget --quiet --output-document=- https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux   /linux_signing_key.pub | gpg --dearmor > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/google-archive.gpg && \
sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' && \
apt-get update && \
apt-get install google-chrome-stable -y --no-install-recommends && \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true

RUN groupadd -r pptruser && useradd -rm -g pptruser -G audio,video pptruser


WORKDIR /app


# copy configs to /app folder
COPY package*.json ./
COPY tsconfig.json ./


# copy source code to /app/src folder
 COPY src /app/src

RUN npm install axios bcrypt cloudinary cookie-parser cors dotenv    express jsonwebtoken puppeteer

 RUN npm install typescript --save-dev
 RUN npm run build





FROM node:18

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install gnupg wget -y && \
wget --quiet --output-document=- https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | gpg --dearmor > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/google-archive.gpg && \
sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' && \
apt-get update && \
apt-get install google-chrome-stable -y --no-install-recommends && \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true

RUN groupadd -r pptruser && useradd -rm -g pptruser -G audio,video  pptruser

WORKDIR /app



COPY package*.json ./ 

RUN npm install axios bcrypt cloudinary cookie-parser cors dotenv   express jsonwebtoken puppeteer

COPY --from=0 /app/build ./build


RUN npm uninstall typescript




USER pptruser

CMD [ "npm", "start"]


EXPOSE 6000
```

The code to create pdf:
export const httpCreatePDF = async(req: Request, res:Response)=>{

```
const url = req.body.url;
const prevPublicURL = req.body.prevPublicURL;
const tripId = req.body.tripId;

res.sendStatus(200);
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: 'new',
executablePath: '/usr/bin/google-chrome',
ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions'],
            args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
});
const page = await browser.newPage();
try {
await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});

const pdf = await page.pdf(
    { format: 'A4', });

await browser.close();

//delete prev pdf if it exist in cloudinary

if(prevPublicURL){
    await deleteAllFiles({filesToDelete: [prevPublicURL]});
};

//upload the file to cloudinary
const uploadResponse =  await cloudinaryBufferUpload(pdf) as any;

const response = {
    pdfImageURL: uploadResponse?.secure_url,
    pdfPublicURL: uploadResponse?.public_id,
    tripId: tripId
}


const webHookReq = await axios.post(sanitizedConfig.WEBHOOK_URL_PDF, response);

    if(webHookReq?.status === 200){

        return 
    }
    else{

       await axios.post(sanitizedConfig.WEBHOOK_URL_PDF, response); 
    } 
  return 
 } catch (error) {
 await browser.close();
 throw error
 }

 }
```

How can I run a more optimized docker image build that would reduce the size. That may fix the deployment error I have in Render host.

Answer (score 0):

Puppeteer have official docker image which should be optimized. I think you can tried it at first.
https://pptr.dev/guides/docker

It works on my free Render account.

Comment: Thank you for replying me. Whhat do you make of the issue that people raised about the puppeteer official image granting too much access to the user. This is what I'm talking about: According to puppeteer documentation, the image is meant for running the browser in sandbox mode and therefore, running the image requires the SYS_ADMIN capability. Some internet articles said that is a security bridge. I don't know. I am not an expert in docker. I simply want to use it to create pdf for my main api. It completes runs outside my main api and sends a response to my main api when pdf is created